# Mocking Joda DateTime method using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I want `millis` to return specified value.

```
public long myMethod(){
    DateTime nowDateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    long millis = nowDateTime.getMillis();
    System.out.println(millis);
}
```

I tried this with no luck.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DateTime.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.crypto.*", "javax.management*" })
...
...
public void testMyMethod(){
    DateTime nowDateTime = PowerMockito.mock(DateTime.class);
    Mockito.when(nowDateTime.getMillis()).thenReturn(10L);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you called `@PrepareForTest` on `DateTime`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just use the `org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils#setCurrentMillisFixed` method of JodaTime which was designed to fix `new DateTime()` to a different time than the current time. To return to the normal time use `org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils#setCurrentMillisSystem` afterwards. No mocking needed.

```
@Test
public void test() {
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(10L);
// .. your code
}

@After
public void cleanup() {
// Make sure to cleanup afterwards
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Using this code basically I 'freeze' the time, right? Thank you, @Leonard.

Comment: Yes it freezes the time.